# Filterig/removing/excluding private IPs with port from a nested list

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, list-comprehension

What:
Python 2.7 is being used.

I am using the virustotal API to generate a list of IP's, in list format. When I run type() on the object, it returns list. At the bottom is an example of the data. Is there any way to make a filter,regexp list comprehension or some wildcard system to remove all IP's starting with 10. 172.16-172.31 and 192.168?

Reason:

There are some common IP's that get generated from the reports, but they are useless to me. I made a list comprehension to filter out specific addresses, but the list is growing and its quickly becoming obvious the list to exclude the main list will slow things down. I want to remove all none important IP's, so I dont slow down my script with useless commits to its DB.

How:

```
unique = [xte for xte in unique if xte not in fil2]

fil2 = [['255.255.255.255',67],['137.170.185.211',123],['213.186.33.99',53],['10.0.2.15',68]]
```

Example: of data:

```
>>> fil2 = [['255.255.255.255',67],['137.170.185.211',123],['213.186.33.99',53],['10.0.2.15',68]]
>>> type(fil2)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Also see the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module in the standard library (Python 3.3+) or the [`netaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) package (Python < 3.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
dont_start_with_these = ('10.', '172.16.', '172.31.', '192.168')

filtered_ip = [ip for ip in fil2 if not ip[0].startswith(dont_start_with_these)]
```

EDIT: This is a more compact solution, as suggested by Vizjerei

Comment: This looks promising, but I keep getting this error, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'", good material for future reference.

Comment: Updated, but Vizjerei answer, once fixed, is more compact.

Comment: I ended up going with this option, but Vizjrei looks great to, thank you both very much, I will come back and upvote when I can. It works wonderfully.

Comment: Not a python question but network one. Is `172.17.1.1` not considered as a private IP? Why excluding only `172.16` and `172.31`?

Answer (score 0):

How about make a list comprehension and make a `startswith` like:

```
ips = [ip for ip in file2[0] if not str(ip[0]).startswith(('192.168.','10.','172.16.','172.31.')) ]
```

Comment: Jeez, it never occurred to me that `startswith` accepts a tuple. Shame on me. Though you should add some parenthesis. Moreover, you should add a dot to the last two prefixes, or they'll filter out more than expected.

Comment: I can recognize this very well, but I am getting this error. The more I see list comprehensions the more I enjoy their utility.
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @Vizjerei Nope: the parenthesis are needed around the start with parameters, or you'll get `TypeError: startswith() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Germano thx didn't check if it works but now it should work, edit it again